# Redirect all pages without a single one

Tags: .htaccess

I would like to redirect my complete domain, but without the file "special_file.html".

This doesn't work:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !special_file\.html
RewriteRule .* http://new-domain.com/ [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

If I access http://old-domain.com/special-file.html, it will be redirected to the new server too. Why?

Comment: Do you have any other directives in your `.htaccess` file or server config? Or any other `.htaccess` files? The directives you posted look "OK" - have you cleared your browser cache? (Note that your directive redirects everything to the homepage on the new-domain - this is undesirable from an SEO perspective.)

Comment: This is the entiered `.htaccess` file and I checked the redirect by an external `HTTP` Headers validator. There is a `Localtion:` inside for this file.

Comment: You mean there is a `Location:` HTTP response header? Well, there is nothing wrong with the directive you posted that would cause this, so "something else" may be triggering the redirect? Try changing the status code on the directive to 302 - does this change the status on the response?

Comment: The problem seems to be, the `!` will not be accepted. If I remove it, requests to `special_file.html` will be redirected, but no other file. This is like I expect it. But if I add the `!` all requests will be redirected - also requests to `special_file.html`. The server is Apache 2.4.7 - a old update. Maybe too old...

Comment: "the `!` will not be accepted." - Hhhmm, but that doesn't make sense - the problem must be elsewhere IMO. The `!` negation operator is such a fundamental part of Apache config (not just mod_rewrite) - many things would break. By coincidence, my local test server is also Apache 2.4.7 and that works just fine.

Comment: Not that this isn't the issue, but your regex is over-generic, as it matches `special_file.html` anywhere in the URL-path. If you specifically only wanted to exclude the URL `/special_file.html`, then you should use the _CondPattern_ `!^/special_file\.html$`. Since you are only excluding a single URL, you don't actually need the additional _condition_; you could just use the `RewriteRule` _pattern_ instead (which would in fact be preferable) - although none of these things should change your current outcome.

Comment: "If I access `http://old-domain.com/special-file.html`, ..." - Just noticed you have a _hyphen_ in your stated URL, but an _underscore_ in your directive?! Or is that just a typo in your question?